# Python Regex - If Statement equal to 'string' and match entire line

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, if-statement

I have a script that prints all the lines between header lines, but it only works with my dummy data, so I am trying to match the entire line after a certain string.

Say I have this data in a text file:

> Dumb Data
>
> index1 0000
>
> random data
>
> index1 0000
>
> random data
>
> index2 0000

The script is able to extract all lines after index 1 and stop before index 2, but it only works if the index line matches extactly in my if statment. Meaning if I delete everything after "index1" it works just fine. So I attempted to use regular expressions, based off reading the python documentation here https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html.

Here is my  code:
It works withtout the regular expressions parts, and if I swap out result1 and result2 with the extract strings I need. What am I missing? I use the '.' to match everything after 'index1', correct?

```
import re

myvar = False
prog = re.compile('.')
result1 = prog.match('index1')
result2 = prog.match('index2')

with open('Sample Test.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if result1 in line:
            myvar = True
            print (line)

        elif result2 in line:
            myvar = False
            print (line)

        elif myvar == True:
            print(line)
            continue
```

I get this  traceback when I try running it:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\mytest\test.py", line 10, in
>    if result1 in line: TypeError: 'in ' requires string as left > operand, not _sre.SRE_Match

Comment: that's not the way regex match should be used like _at all_

Comment: Well darn, thought I had something. If you see my question history, you'd see my struggle.. Ha..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't using regex right... This is how you should do it.

```
import re

myvar = False
with open('Sample Test.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if re.search(r'index1', line):
            myvar = True
            print (line)

        elif re.search(r'index2', line):
            myvar = False
            print (line)

        elif myvar:
            print(line)
            continue
```

Comment: Hey this works perfectly, and I think I under stand how it work. Thanks!!